# Canvas .fillText function not working after the first time

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am just trying to draw a letter on canvas. I am using `filltext()` to draw a character on canvas.

It is working on the first time but if I go back to menu and try again the character is not displaying on the canvas.

While I am trying to find any errors with console log, it is showing me function is called and the letters are also drawn (I am calculating the number of pixels on canvas) but somehow I am not getting letter on canvas display.

```
function setupCanvas(character) {
    canvasVar.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvasVar.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvasCx.lineWidth = 14;
    canvasCx.lineCap = 'round';
    canvasCx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 50)';
    //canvasCx.strokeStyle = $rootScope.userPreferedColor;
    canvasCx.font = 'bold 25em helvetica';
    canvasCx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    canvasCx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    drawletter(character);
    //pixels = canvasCx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasVar.width, canvasVar.height);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(pixels))
}

function drawletter(char) {
    //making letter a global variable - not the right way :) dirty solution
    letter = char;
    centerx = (canvasVar.width - canvasCx.measureText(letter).width) / 2;
    centery = canvasVar.height / 2;
    //canvasCx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasVar.width, canvasVar.height);
    canvasCx.fillText(letter, centerx, centery);
    //getting the border for the letter only
    pixels = canvasCx.getImageData(centerx,0,canvasCx.measureText(letter).width,canvasVar.height);
    console.log("letter is drawn to the canvas "+ getpixelamount(255, 0, 0));
}//end of draw letter
```

Find the Total Code at : [github repo](https://github.com/anilkunchalaece/debugLearn)

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, we don't know what is going on in your "menu"-code.

Comment: find the code at [link] (https://github.com/anilkunchalaece/debugLearn).

find the canvas at www/templates/practiceView.html and respective JS code at www/controllers/practiceViewController.js

click on list1 or list 2 then select a letter to go to canvas view then go back to menu using btn placed on canvas and select another letter, now the letter wont be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You remove page cache it will solve problem